# python pandas, a function will be applied to the combinations of the elements in one row based on a condition on the other row

Tags: python, function, pandas, combinations

It seems like there are similar questions, but I couldn't find a proper answer. Let's say this is my dataframe which has different observations for a different brand of cars:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Car' : ['BMW_1', 'BMW_2', 'BMW_3', 'WW_1','WW_2','Fiat_1', 'Fiat_2'],
                       'distance'   : [10,25,22,24,37,33,49]})
```

For simplicity, let's assume that I have a function  multiples first element by two and second by three:

```
def my_func(x,y):
   z = 2x + 3y
   return z
```

I want to get pairwise combinations of the distances covered by the cars and use them in my_func. But there are two conditions are that x and y can not be same brands and combinations should not be duplicated. Desired output is something like this:

```
  Car      Distance   Combinations                                
0  BMW_1   10         (BMW_1,WW_1),(BMW_1,WW_2),(BMW_1,Fiat_1),(BMW_1,Fiat_1)
1  BMW_2   25         (BMW_2,WW_1),(BMW_2,WW_2),(BMW_2,Fiat_1),(BMW_2,Fiat_1)
2  BMW_3   22         (BMW_3,WW_1),(BMW_3,WW_2),(BMW_3,Fiat_1),(BMW_3,Fiat_1)
3  WW_1    24         (WW_1, Fiat_1),(WW_1, Fiat_2)
4  WW_2    37         (WW_2, Fiat_1),(WW_2, Fiat_2)
5  Fiat_1  33         None
6  Fiat_2  49         None

//Output
[120, 134, 156, 178]
[113, 145, 134, 132]
[114, 123, 145, 182]
[153, 123] 
[120, 134] 
None 
None
```

Note: I made up the numbers for output.

Next Step I want to get maximum numbers from the arrays of 'output' row for each brand. And the final data should look like

```
  Car  Max_Distance
0 BMW  178
1 WW   153
2 Fiat None
```

I will be grateful if someone could help me

Comment: Just to be clear... you do **not** want to compare any BMW with any other BMW?

Comment: Yes, exactly, only with different brands

Comment: Order matters? Given z = 2x + 3y: bmw_fiat 2*25 + 3*49 vs fiat+bmw 2*49 + 3*25 z is different.

Comment: No it doesn't matter in the real function, it could be something like x + y.  I just want to group by the first element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [49]: x = pd.DataFrame(np.triu(squareform(pdist(df[['distance']], my_func))),
    ...:                  columns=df.Car.str.split('_').str[0],
    ...:                  index=df.Car.str.split('_').str[0]).replace(0, np.nan)
    ...:

In [50]: x[x.apply(lambda col: col.index != col.name)].max(1).max(level=0)
Out[50]:
Car
BMW     197.0
Fiat      NaN
WW      221.0
dtype: float64
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can do something like the following:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

def my_func(x,y):
    return 2*x + 3*y

x = pd.DataFrame(
    squareform(pdist(df[['distance']], my_func)),
    columns=df.Car.str.split('_').str[0],
    index=df.Car.str.split('_').str[0])
```

it produced:

```
In [269]: x
Out[269]:
Car     BMW    BMW    BMW     WW     WW   Fiat   Fiat
Car
BMW     0.0   95.0   86.0   92.0  131.0  119.0  167.0
BMW    95.0    0.0  116.0  122.0  161.0  149.0  197.0
BMW    86.0  116.0    0.0  116.0  155.0  143.0  191.0
WW     92.0  122.0  116.0    0.0  159.0  147.0  195.0
WW    131.0  161.0  155.0  159.0    0.0  173.0  221.0
Fiat  119.0  149.0  143.0  147.0  173.0    0.0  213.0
Fiat  167.0  197.0  191.0  195.0  221.0  213.0    0.0
```

exluding the same brand:

```
In [270]: x.apply(lambda col: col.index != col.name)
Out[270]:
Car     BMW    BMW    BMW     WW     WW   Fiat   Fiat
Car
BMW   False  False  False   True   True   True   True
BMW   False  False  False   True   True   True   True
BMW   False  False  False   True   True   True   True
WW     True   True   True  False  False   True   True
WW     True   True   True  False  False   True   True
Fiat   True   True   True   True   True  False  False
Fiat   True   True   True   True   True  False  False

In [273]: x[x.apply(lambda col: col.index != col.name)]
Out[273]:
Car     BMW    BMW    BMW     WW     WW   Fiat   Fiat
Car
BMW     NaN    NaN    NaN   92.0  131.0  119.0  167.0
BMW     NaN    NaN    NaN  122.0  161.0  149.0  197.0
BMW     NaN    NaN    NaN  116.0  155.0  143.0  191.0
WW     92.0  122.0  116.0    NaN    NaN  147.0  195.0
WW    131.0  161.0  155.0    NaN    NaN  173.0  221.0
Fiat  119.0  149.0  143.0  147.0  173.0    NaN    NaN
Fiat  167.0  197.0  191.0  195.0  221.0    NaN    NaN
```

selecting maximum per row:

```
In [271]: x[x.apply(lambda col: col.index != col.name)].max(1)
Out[271]:
Car
BMW     167.0
BMW     197.0
BMW     191.0
WW      195.0
WW      221.0
Fiat    173.0
Fiat    221.0
dtype: float64
```

max per brand:

```
In [276]: x[x.apply(lambda col: col.index != col.name)].max(1).max(level=0)
Out[276]:
Car
BMW     197.0
Fiat    221.0
WW      221.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. if I have to apply it to a large csv file, it would be efficient?

Comment: @edyvedy13, you will never know until you try it ;-)

Comment: I am almost there but the only thing is that it should be like combinations of elements, I don't wanna compare WW again with BMW when I get the results for BMW.then, I wanna match WW with Fiat and Fiat with nothing basically.

Comment: I am even willing to pay for it if someone could solve my problem as I am working on it for 4 days :/

Comment: ,Sorry I just saw it, If we think about the combinations and groupby functions, and when we say group by the first element, there should be nothing left for Fiat. It is little bit complecated :/

Comment: So it just returns the upper triangle, perfect :)

Comment: @edyvedy13, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
i, j = np.tril_indices(len(df), 1)

def my_func(x,y):
    z = 2 * x + 3 * y
    return z

d = df.distance.values
c = df.Car.values
s = pd.Series(my_func(d[i], d[j]), [c[i], c[j]])

def test_name(df):
    name = df.index[0]
    n1, n2 = map(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], name)
    return n1 != n2

s.groupby(level=[0, 1]).filter(test_name).groupby(level=1).apply(list)

BMW_1       [78, 104, 96, 128]
BMW_2     [123, 149, 141, 173]
BMW_3     [114, 140, 132, 164]
Fiat_1                   [173]
WW_1           [116, 138, 170]
WW_2                [177, 209]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Oh maybe I was not clear enough, sorry, also I don't want WW and Fiat to match with their own kinds :(